# Can't load styles using pug4j template engine in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jade4j

I try to load style from my resources folder (/resources/static/styles.css) but embedded tomcat answers 404.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class PugTemplateConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateLoader templateLoader() {
        SpringTemplateLoader templateLoader
                = new SpringTemplateLoader();
        templateLoader.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates/");
        templateLoader.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateLoader.setSuffix(".pug");
        return templateLoader;
    }
    @Bean
    public PugConfiguration pugConfiguration() {
        PugConfiguration configuration = new PugConfiguration();
        configuration.setCaching(false);
        configuration.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader());
        return configuration;
    }
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        PugViewResolver viewResolver = new PugViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setConfiguration(pugConfiguration());
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

templates/index.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css")
    title document title
  body
    p hello, world!
```

styles located in resources/static/css/styles.css
in target folder I can see it in /static/css/styles.css

spring log:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : GET "/css/style.css", parameters={}
WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping for GET /css/style.css
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

I tried to move style.css to 'templates' folder, but it did not help